# Visual Studio 2008 - show heap

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, stack, heap-memory

Is it possible to view the heap and stack during debugging?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK, the main windows you'd want to use are the Locals (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>) and Autos (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>) windows which MSDN has as:

The Locals window displays variables local to the current context or scope. Usually, this means the procedure or function you are currently executing. The debugger populates this window automatically. In Visual C#, when the Exception Assistant is disabled, the Locals window also displays a pseudovariable $exception whenever there is an active exception. You can expand the pseudovariable to see details of the exception.

The Autos window displays variables used in the current line of code and the preceding line of code. For native C++, the Autos window displays function return values as well. Like the Locals window, the Autos window is populated automatically by the debugger.

...and for the Stack there's the Call Stack window (Debug -> Windows -> Call Stack) or <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

However, I get the feeling this isn't what you're after.

If you are looking for an "in-memory" view you might be able to make use of Visual Studio's Memory windows which can be accessed from the Debug -> Windows -> Memory -> Memory x menus (where x is 1-4) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, 1-4.

As a few people have now mentioned, there are a couple of other external tools which are quite useful for memory debugging (I use mainly SysInternals tools and the Debugging Tools for Windows).

Answer (score 6):

You need the "Call Stack Window"...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx

> By using the Call Stack window, you can view the function or procedure calls that are currently on the stack.

And for the Heap, the "Memory Window"...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e(VS.80).aspx

> The Memory window provides a view into the memory space used by your application.

"Restoring Hidden Debugger Commands" may also be useful...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k643651(VS.80).aspx

As you get into debugging memory, other debuggers will be more useful.  As someone suggested, WinDbg is excellent for memory debugging.  I use IDA Pro Disassembler a lot myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the call stack while debugging, but I assume that's not what you're looking for. You might want to try Windbg and SOS, which are GREAT for debugging memory issues. A bit steep on the learning curve, but the payback is HUGE.

[Microsoft Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to look at the raw memory for some reason you can open the "Memory" debug window from "`Debug->Windows->Memory`" and write the address you want to look at in the edit box. You can also write in the edit box any expression which evaluates to an address and it'll show you that address, for instance `&variable`

This is not very useful for actually looking at variables because you'll have a tough time parsing the raw bytes into meaningful values but it can be useful for debugging situations where you suspect there are buffer overruns or memory that is overwritten unexpectedly. It is particularly useful when used in conjunction with [data-breakpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I figured I'd update it anyway...

Visual Studio 2015 comes with the Memory Usage Monitor built right in to the Diagnostic Tools panel.  If you take snapshots before, during, and after what you want to inspect, you can retroactively peek at the heap view of those snapshots.

Hope this helps someone.